# VBA any way to count number of success match of vlookup/ index match

Tags: vba, count

using index match to copy data from table 2 to table1 if name (exist in table 1 and 2) is matched.

any way I could count how many matched is made after a run of the sub?

Code:

```
Sub Find_the_value() 

    Dim i As Integer 
    i = 0 

    For Each Cl In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A10") 
        If Cl.Value = 5 Then 
            i = i + 1 
            Exit For 
        End If 
    Next Cl 
    MsgBox i 

End Sub
```

Comment: Please share some data and expected outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Have you got the existing code? It should be relatively straightforward to declare an integer and increment it each time the match is found.

EDIT:

```
Sub Find_the_value()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Cl As Range

    i = 0

    For Each Cl In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A10")

        If Cl.Value = 5 Then

            i = i + 1

        End If

    Next Cl

    MsgBox i

End Sub
```

Comment: for trail purpose , made a sheet with 5 is Range("A1:A10")   trying to get message return 10  with below code:

Comment: Sub Find_the_value()
Dim i As Integer
i = 0

For Each Cl In ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A10")


 If Cl.Value = 5 Then
  i = i + 1
  Exit For
 End If
Next Cl

MsgBox i
End Sub

Comment: Added your code to the answer. It works, but is too hard to read in the comment. Also added Cl as a declared variable.

Comment: thank you for your response .    it is not working,   message box return "1"  to me , i expect it return 10

Comment: Fixed it - the "Exit For" should not have been in the If statement. That meant the routine was ending on the first loop. This should work now.

Comment: Use Long rather than Integer.